# Can i use this statement?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
?>
```

Now instead of `example.txt` can i use `"http://engine.searchr.us/web-search.phtml?search=TEST+SEARCH"` ?

Is it possible ?

Comment: It depends. Why don't you try out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, as long as allow_url_fopen is enabled in your PHP config.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. As the manual says:

> Both source and dest  may now be URLs if the "fopen wrappers" have been enabled. See fopen() for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can read remote files using PHP

```
$contents = '';
$file = fopen ("http://www.example.com/", "r");
if (!$file) {
    echo "<p>Unable to open remote file.\n";
    exit;
}
while (!feof ($file)) {
    $line = fgets ($file, 1024);
    $contents .= $line;
}
fclose($file);

echo $contents;
```

Source

http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

Answer (score 0):

As Emil Vikström said you must have [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) directive enabled. Documentation also says that this directive can be set *only* into `php.ini` file.